# SQL REGEXP_LIKE Strings with 3 words

Tags: sql, regex

This homework problem I have is to use a regexp_like expression to find course names that have three words.

The current expression I'm using is like '\w\s\w\s\w$'. However it gets no results when the $ sign is added. Without that symbol, it shows the three word strings and also the four word ones. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing to test? No code, no expression...And no religion too... post some code, what you have tried so far, some data for testing and also wich RDBM's are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an anchor that marks the end of a line.

`\w\s\w\s\w' should only match 3 letters separated by spaces. You could try something like;

```
'^\w+\s\w+\s\w+$'
```